# Random Number generator fail

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, functional-programming

How do I get the program to loop back around from the beginning if the incorrect number is picked? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried `if`s, `do while`s, `while`s, and `if else`s:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArrayProblms
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
            RandomNumberGenerator();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void RandomNumberGenerator()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int userValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int randValue = rand.Next(1, 11);
            int attempts = 0;

            if (userValue == randValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have guessed correctly!");
            }
            while (userValue != randValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have guessed incorrectly");
                attempts++;
                Console.WriteLine("You have made {0} incorrect guesses", attempts);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the condition to end the program and what is the condition to loop through again and again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `do...while` to continue asking user to enter the new number until he guessed correctly.

Example below:

```
public static void RandomNumberGenerator()
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    int randValue = rand.Next(1, 11);
    int attempts = 0;

    // do...while cycle to ask user to enter new value each time the used has been wrong
    do
    {
        // read user input
        int userValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // if user guessed correct
        if (userValue == randValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have guessed correctly!");
            // go away from do...while loop
            // it will stop asking user and will exit from the method
            break;
        }

        // if user has been wrong
        Console.WriteLine("You have guessed incorrectly");
        // increment attempts count
        attempts++;
        Console.WriteLine("You have made {0} incorrect guesses", attempts);
    }
    // and repeat until user guessed correctly
    while(userValue != randValue)
}
```

Comment: `Try this:` doesn't explain anything. Do we have to compare the codes line by line to see what you have fixed?

Comment: I put a comments to describe what the example code does. I hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

You should put `int userValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` inside the loop and check input on every iteration. `break` must be only if `userValue == randValue`:

```
    public static void RandomNumberGenerator()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randValue = rand.Next(1, 11);
        int attempts = 0;


        while (true)
        {
            int userValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // input inside the loop
            if (userValue == randValue) // checking inside the loop
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have guessed correctly!");
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("You have guessed incorrectly");
            attempts++;
            Console.WriteLine("You have made {0} incorrect guesses",            attempts);                
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you need to put the `Console.ReadLine` inside a while loop and `break` out of the loop only when the user's value matches.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
Generate random number
while (true) {
    Get value from user
    If it matches, break
}
```